# How to display table content using Qtableview after selecting a vector layer in Pyqt4?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, pyqt4

I'm developing a QGIS plugin using QtDesigner and pyqt4.
I have a comboBox of my vector layers and I want to show the table of the selected layer.
I used this code for my comboBox:

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""

    allLayers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    allLyrNames = [lyr.name() for lyr in allLayers]
    self.dlg.updateCombos(allLyrNames)

    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.

        grdLayerName = self.dlg.getGridLayer()

        pass
```

And these two functions:

```
def getGridLayer(self):
    return(unicode(self.GridLayerCombo.currentText()))
def updateCombos(self, items):
    if len(items) > 0:
        self.GridLayerCombo.clear()

        for item in items:
            self.GridLayerCombo.addItem(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at the bottom part sample from https://webgeodatavore.github.io/pyqgis-samples/gui-group/QgsAttributeTableView.html for a solution (disclosure: I'm the author of the content)

You may also look at https://webgeodatavore.github.io/pyqgis-samples/gui-group/QgsMapLayerComboBox.html for a component to select layers

Both samples are standalone: run them in the QGIS Python console after opening any QGIS project. You will need to change `iface` reference while integrating in a plugin.